# jsoup to get div elements with classes

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup parsing and I want to get the list of all the companies on this page: https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup
Now, a way to do this is actually to inspect the page with the div tags relevant to what I need.
However, when I call the method :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=Startup").get();
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Firstly I cannot even find those DIV tags in my consol html output, (the ones which are supposed to give a list of the companies)
Secondly, even if I did find it, how can I find a certain Div element with class name :

```
div class=" dc59 frw44 _a _jm"
```

Pardon the jargon, I have no idea how to go through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data are not embedded in the page but they are retrieved using subsequent API calls :

- a POST https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data to get an `ids` array & a token named `hexdigest`
- a GET https://angel.co/companies/startups to retrieve company data using the output from the previous request

The above is repeated for each page (thus a new token & a list of ids are needed for each page). This process can be seen using Chrome dev console in Network tabs.

The first `POST` request gives JSON output but the second request (`GET`) gives HTML data in a property of a JSON object.

The following extracts the company filter :

```
private static CompanyFilter getCompanyFilter(final String filter, final int page) throws IOException {

    String response = Jsoup.connect("https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
            .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .data("filter_data[company_types][]=", filter)
            .data("sort", "signal")
            .data("page", String.valueOf(page))
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .post().body().text();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    return gson.fromJson(response, CompanyFilter.class);
}
```

Then the following extracts companies :

```
private static List<Company> getCompanies(final CompanyFilter companyFilter) throws IOException {

    List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

    URLConnection urlConn = new URL("https://angel.co/companies/startups?" + companyFilter.buildRequest()).openConnection();
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    urlConn.connect();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    HtmlContainer htmlObj = new Gson().fromJson(reader, HtmlContainer.class);

    Element doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlObj.getHtml());
    Elements data = doc.select("div[data-_tn]");

    if (data.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < data.size(); i++) {
            companies.add(new Company(data.get(i).select("a").first().attr("title"),
                    data.get(i).select("a").first().attr("href"),
                    data.get(i).select("div.pitch").first().text()));
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("no data");
    }
    return companies;
}
```

The main function :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int pageCount = 1;
    List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        System.out.println("get page n°" + pageCount);
        CompanyFilter companyFilter = getCompanyFilter("Startup", pageCount);
        pageCount++;
        System.out.println("digest     : " + companyFilter.getDigest());
        System.out.println("count      : " + companyFilter.getTotalCount());
        System.out.println("array size : " + companyFilter.getIds().size());
        System.out.println("page       : " + companyFilter.getpage());

        companies.addAll(getCompanies(companyFilter));

        if (companies.size() == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("size     : " + companies.size());
        }
    }
}
```

`Company`, `CompanyFilter` & `HtmlContainer` are model class :

```
class CompanyFilter {

    @SerializedName("ids")
    private List<Integer> mIds;

    @SerializedName("hexdigest")
    private String mDigest;

    @SerializedName("total")
    private String mTotalCount;

    @SerializedName("page")
    private int mPage;

    @SerializedName("sort")
    private String mSort;

    @SerializedName("new")
    private boolean mNew;

    public List<Integer> getIds() {
        return mIds;
    }

    public String getDigest() {
        return mDigest;
    }

    public String getTotalCount() {
        return mTotalCount;
    }

    public int getpage() {
        return mPage;
    }

    private String buildRequest() {
        String out = "total=" + mTotalCount + "&";
        out += "sort=" + mSort + "&";
        out += "page=" + mPage + "&";
        out += "new=" + mNew + "&";
        for (int i = 0; i < mIds.size(); i++) {
            out += "ids[]=" + mIds.get(i) + "&";
        }
        out += "hexdigest=" + mDigest + "&";
        return out;
    }
}

private static class Company {

    private String mLink;
    private String mName;
    private String mDescription;

    public Company(String name, String link, String description) {
        mLink = link;
        mName = name;
        mDescription = description;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return mLink;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }
} 

private static class HtmlContainer {

    @SerializedName("html")
    private String mHtml;

    public String getHtml() {
        return mHtml;
    }
}
```

The full code is also available [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/ea7b89654fee50f9e6b7b09ae5500c12)

Comment: this was just what i was looking for.
You're a lifesaver. Thank You <3

Comment: There is one more Problem.
The line : 

    Company(data.get(i).select("a").first().attr("title").replace("\\\"", ""),

Doesn't give the full title of the company; if there are two words in it, say for instance 'Abd Motors', you only get 'Abd', @Bertrand

Comment: @vidhi ok I've updated the answer, in fact I noticed that the GET https://angel.co/companies/startups was giving JSON data & expected to parse it with Jsoup but it's a little tricky because when specifying `ignoreContentType` it doesn't parse correctly the escaped quotes inside json, so I've updated the above by parsing the object with Gson and extract the html which avoid usage of all those ugly `replac‌​e("\\\"", "")`